# Measure and integration(In specific about $L^1$)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The exercise consists of the following:
Let $ \left (X, \mathcal{M}, \mu \right) $ be a measure space and $ f \in L^1 (\mu) $.

If $A \in \mathcal{M}$ is such that $0< \mu(A) < \infty$, show that $|f(x)| \le \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \int_A |f|\,d\mu$ for some $x \in A $.

What ideas can you give me to solve it?

I can't really think of anything.

Comment: Sweet Christmas. Do not put spaces between your backslashes and your command names in $\rm\LaTeX$. Please review the edits I made to your post, including looking at the raw $\rm\LaTeX$ itself, and let me know if this is what you intended.

Comment: If $|f|>\frac{1}{\mu(A)}\int_A|f|$ on $A$ and $0<\mu(A)<\infty$,  then, integrating over $A$, gives $\int_A|f|\,d\mu>\int_A\int |f|\,d\mu$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Dang it  I've been waiting for OP to respond before posting this as a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to notice that if $g\geq0$ is a integrable with respect to a measure $\mu$,  and $A=\{g>0\}$ has positive measure (i.e. $\mu(A)>0$), then it must be the case that $\int g\,d\mu>0$.

To see that, notie that $\{g>0\}=\bigcup_n\{g>\frac1n\}$. Thus, there is $n_0$ such that $\mu\big(\{g>\frac{1}{n_0}\}\big)>0$. Consequently
$$\int g\,d\mu\geq\int_{\{g>\tfrac{1}{n_0}\}}g\,d\mu\geq\frac{1}{n_0}\mu\big(\{g>\tfrac{1}{n_0}\}\big)>0$$

---

In your posting, If there is no point $x\in A$ for which $|f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{\mu(A)}\int_A |f|\,d\mu=\alpha_A$, then it means that for all $x\in A$,
$$|f(x)|>\frac{1}{\mu(A)}\int_A\,|f|\,d\mu=\alpha_A$$
Define $g(x):=\big(|f(x)|-\alpha_A\big)\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ (where $\mathbb{1}_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise). As $A=\{g>0\}$ and $\mu(A)>0$ by assumption, the statement above implies that
$$0<\int g\,d\mu=\Big(\int_A|f|\,d\mu\Big)-\mu(A)\alpha_A=0$$
which is absurd. The conclusion is that there must be $x\in A$ for which $|f(x)|\leq\alpha_A$.

---

**Obs:** Notice that a  similar argument shows that in fact, there exists $x'\in A$ such that $ |f(x')|\geq \alpha_A$.

Comment: Can you explain to me why this inequality occurs? $\int_{\{g>1/ n\}}gd\mu \geq 1/ n_0 \mu(\{g>1/n_0\})>0$

Comment: Sure, this is basically the trick: $g\mathbb{1}_{\{g>\tfrac{1}{n_0}\}}\geq \frac{1}{n_0}\mathbb{1}_{\{g>\tfrac{1}{n_0}\}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose that $|f(x)| > \frac{1}{\mu(A)}\int_A |f|\,d\mu$ for a.e. $x$. What happens if you integrate both sides over $A$? Do you see why it is important that $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$ for this argument?

Comment: How would you solve this without using contradiction? I got stuck on trying to prove the existence of the point.

Comment: Not sure if you can without knowing extra information about $f$. Any methods I can think of for a general situation (even restricting to continuous) end up requiring pointwise knowledge of $f$ (or something pretty close to it).

Comment: @Cameron Williams If I integrate both sides over A, I get the following contradiction. $\int_{A}|f|d\mu>\int_{A}|f|d\mu$